# Is the function $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi(f(x,\omega)) \cdot \ \chi_{[-1,1]}(f(x,\omega)) $ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f:[-1,1]\times[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ be the function $f(x,\omega) = x^3 + \omega$, then whe can define the following family $\left\{\mathbb P_x\right\}_{x\in[-1,1]}$ of Borel measures on $[-1,1]$
\begin{align*}\mathbb P_x: \mathcal B([0,1])&\to \mathbb R_+ \\
A&\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} \chi_A \circ f(x,\omega) d\omega,  
\end{align*}
where $\chi_A$ the characteristic function of the set $A$, *i.e.*, $\chi_A(x) =1$ if $x\in A$, $\chi_A(x) = 0$, if $x \not\in A$.

Let $\varphi:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R_+$, a bounded measurable function, then we define
$$\mathbb E_x (\varphi) = \int_{[-1,1]}\varphi(y) \ \text{d}\mathbb P_x(y) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi(f(x,\omega)) \cdot \ \chi_{[-1,1]}(f(x,\omega))\ \text{d} \omega.$$

> **My question:** Is the function $G:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R_+$, $G(x) := \mathbb E_x(\varphi)$ continuous?

---

### My attempt

Note that $$-1\leq x^3 + \omega \leq 1 \Rightarrow -1-x^3 \leq \omega \leq 1-x^3,$$
then 
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi(f(x,\omega)) \cdot \ \chi_{[-1,1]}(f(x,\omega))\ \text{d} \omega&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1\lor-1-x^3}^{1\land 1+x^3}\varphi(x^3+\omega) \ \text{d} \omega\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1+x^3\lor -1}^{1+x^3\land 1}\varphi(y) \ \text{d} y,
\end{align*}
where $a\lor b = \max\{a,b\}$ and $a\land b = \min\{a,b\}$.

Once $-1+x^3\lor -1$ and $1+x^3\land 1$ are continuous $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1+x^3\lor -1}^{1+x^3\land 1}\varphi(y) \ \text{d} y$ is continuous, is this right?